# elasticsSearch: match only if the full text of the query is in a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to  match only if the full text of the query is in a field.

Example:

```
Query : "Hello"
Field : "Hello world"
**should not match**.


Query : "Hello"
Field : "Hello"
**should match**.
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a term query for this purpose.

```
GET my-index-000001/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "full_text": "Hello"
    }
  }
}
```

See the documentation for further details on how to use
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: not working for me, actually i am looking in an array of products. "products": "Hello" not working.

Comment: @ayoubben can you provide an example of your docs. then and the mapping, so we can help you better?